# CustomFont (.otf) in Overleaf with pdfLatex and custom fonts package

Tags: fonts, pdftex, overleaf

I am trying to use custom fonts in Overleaf with pdfLatex and a custom fonts package (I have read the Overleaf documentation [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX)). I have placed the following files in my Overleaf directory: GillAltOneMt.otf, GillAltOneMt-Italic, GillAltOneMt-Bold, GillAltOneMt-BoldItalic.

When compiling with LuaLatex, it works. However, not with pdfLatex (Tex Live 2020) - it yields the package error. My questions:

- Is it because I have no fd file (t1mgs.fd) that the error is raised? If so, what should this fd file look like to point to the otf files?
- Is there any other way to change this code, to check for the font files in the root directory instead?

Relevant parts from the fonts package (.sty file):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{uufonts}[...]

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\newif\ifuufonts@systemfonts
\uufonts@systemfontsfalse
\ifluatex
% Then assume we have the fonts and yield error later otherwise.
% (Checking if font exists takes time.)
\uufonts@systemfontstrue
\else
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\fi

[...]

\newif\ifuufonts@sans
\uufonts@sanstrue
\DeclareOption{no-sans}{\uufonts@sansfalse}

[...]

% === Gill Sans ===
\ifuufonts@sans
\IfFileExists{./GillAltOneMT.otf}{
  \setsansfont{GillAltOneMT.otf}[
  BoldFont = GillAltOneMT-Bold.otf ,
  ItalicFont = GillAltOneMT-Italic.otf ,
  BoldItalicFont = GillAltOneMT-BoldItalic.otf]
}{
  \setsansfont{Gill Alt One MT}
}
\fi

[...]

\ifuufonts@sans
\IfFileExists{t1mgs.fd}{
  \renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{mgs}
}{
  \AtEndOfPackage{
    \PackageError{uufonts}
    {The Gill Sans font is not installed for (pdf)TeX. Maybe try lualatex instead}
    {If you continue, that font is simply not used}}
  \relax}
\fi % sans
```

Comment: You need XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to use OTF fonts directly

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DG', however, like I wrote I am aware of this. I was wondering how I can get it to work with pdfLatex.

Comment: There is no easy way to "get it to work with pdflatex". You have to convert the font and generate all the files needed by pdflatex. Although there are tools to help you with that (e.g. [lcdf](https://www.lcdf.org/type/) and [autoinst] (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/)), I'd say it's not worth it. Don't do it